# Simple contract to contract token transfer failing

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, ropsten

I'm trying to write a contract that combines two different function calls into one transaction, for which I then can hopefully use the CHI gas token. However, for now I can't even get my contract to make a simple uniswap trade.

```
  contract ProxyChi {
     Uniswap uni = Uniswap(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
    
     function simpleTradeCall(uint amtTkIn, uint amtTkOut, address[] memory path) public returns (uint[] memory amounts){
     return uni.swapExactTokensForTokens(amtTkIn, amtTkOut, path, msg.sender, now+120);
    }
 contract Uniswap{   
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}
```

Anytime I want to make a trade in remix, I get the TOKEN_FROM_FAILED problem. I've approved the ProxiChi contract for the outgoing token. Is this just a uniswap specific thing, or am I doing something wrong? My mainnet functions don't have arguments, but do spend tokens. I pass the path as ["addr1", "addr2"] in remix. Is there maybe some other contract I can try that spends a lot of gas (on ropsten)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok my problem was easily solved: My contract needed to hold the tokens, not my account. As such, my contract also needed an ERC20 interface, so I could call "approve".